# I can't get the Fast flag

Tags: relays

More than two years with my middle relay running smoothly. In May of this year it was disconnected from Tor. Since then I never get the flag of Fast, so I don't help the Tor community. My raspberry pi and I are devastated.
Problems with my ISP?
Donald Trump censors me? :)
Thank you in advance to everyone
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

The [`dir-spec`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt) states:

> A router is 'Fast' if it is active, and its bandwidth is either in the top 7/8ths for known active routers **or at least 100KB/s**.

This means that your relay either cannot, or hasn't been seen to, relay at least 100KB/s (that's 100 KBytes/s, or 800KBits/s) by the bandwidth authorities.

This could be for many reasons, it might be that it hasn't been properly measured yet by the bandwidth authorities (e.g. if it's a new relay) or that there has been some local network change or a change on the device the relay is running on that is causing a bottleneck or it could be a change somewhere upstream. There's not enough information to go on to give a definitive root cause but the core of the issue is: It hasn't been measured by the bandwidth authorities to be able to relay data at >100KBytes/s (*and* it's in the bottom 1/8th for relay speed over-all).

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your comments. Indeed with the little information I gave, your various options are all interesting. I give some more information: on my pc, FreeBSD, I started a new relay. But, as with raspberry pi, Raspbian, I can't get the flag Fast.
I don't know whether to think about updating the firmware of the router or, directly, a new policy of my ISP, Vodafone.
Anyway, I insist on thanking you for your answers.
Let Tux and Beastie go with you.